# Show array with variable in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

In my symfony project, I **pass from the Controller a variable** called 'button'.

In this case 'button' has the value 'content' but this is not always.

I need it to display the content of **phrase.content** in the '.html.twig' file but I can't.

**index.html.twig:**

button = 'content'

```
{% for frase in frases %}

    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ frase.id }}</th>
        <td>{{ frase. ~ button }}</td>
    </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

I have tried like this but it gives me the following error:

```
Expected name or number. (500 Internal Server Error)
```

**----EDIT----**

If I put frase.content directly it does, but if I put frase[button], it gives an error

```
Impossible to access a key" content"on an object of class" App \ Entity \ Frase"
that does not implement ArrayAccess interface.
```

Comment: `frase[button]`. done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this twig's check could solve your problem:

```
{% if foo.bar is defined %}
```

See doc: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/defined.html

Also If you want to access object's property you can use twig function

```
attribute
```

Link https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html

So in your case it would be something like:

```
{{ attribute(frase, button) ?? '' }}
```

Also you can additionally check if 'button' variable is defined

Answer (score 0):

`frase.` expects something after the dot. A dot like this in twig is kind of like `'s`: In the table header you ask for `frase's id`. In the table definition (td) element, twig essentially thinks:

> frase's " ~ button"?? I was expecting a property!

If `button` contains the name of the property you wish to show, you can use:

```
frase[button]
```

In that case, if `button` is "content", twig will read it as

> frase's content

PS: did you mean `{% for phrase in phrases %}`?

Comment: If I put frase.content directly it does, but if I put frase[button], it gives an error `Impossible to access a key" content"on an object of class" App \ Entity \ Frase"that does not implement ArrayAccess interface. `